# Does Rust optimize passing temporary structures by value?

Tags: rust

Let's say I have a vector of structures in Rust. Structures are quite big. When I want to insert a new one, I write the code like this:

```
my_vec.push(MyStruct {field1: value1, field2: value2, ... });
```

The push definition is

```
fn push(&mut self, value: T)
```

which means the value is passed by value. I wonder if Rust creates a temporary object first then does a copy to the push function or does it optimize the code so that no temporary objects are created and copied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see. [This program](http://is.gd/B2wmw9):

```
struct LotsOfBytes {
    bytes: [u8; 1024]
}

#[inline(never)]
fn consume(mut lob: LotsOfBytes) {
}

fn main() {
    let lob = LotsOfBytes { bytes: [0; 1024] };
    consume(lob);
}
```

Compiles to the following LLVM IR code:

```
%LotsOfBytes = type { [1024 x i8] }

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define internal fastcc void @_ZN7consume20hf098deecafa4b74bkaaE(%LotsOfBytes* noalias nocapture dereferenceable(1024)) unnamed_addr #0 {
entry-block:
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds %LotsOfBytes* %0, i64 0, i32 0, i64 0
  tail call void @llvm.lifetime.end(i64 1024, i8* %1)
  ret void
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define internal void @_ZN4main20hf3cbebd3154c5390qaaE() unnamed_addr #2 {
entry-block:
  %lob = alloca %LotsOfBytes, align 8
  %lob1 = getelementptr inbounds %LotsOfBytes* %lob, i64 0, i32 0, i64 0
  %arg = alloca %LotsOfBytes, align 8
  %0 = getelementptr inbounds %LotsOfBytes* %lob, i64 0, i32 0, i64 0
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start(i64 1024, i8* %0)
  call void @llvm.memset.p0i8.i64(i8* %lob1, i8 0, i64 1024, i32 8, i1 false)
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds %LotsOfBytes* %arg, i64 0, i32 0, i64 0
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start(i64 1024, i8* %1)
  call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* %1, i8* %0, i64 1024, i32 8, i1 false)
  call fastcc void @_ZN7consume20hf098deecafa4b74bkaaE(%LotsOfBytes* noalias nocapture dereferenceable(1024) %arg)
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end(i64 1024, i8* %1)
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end(i64 1024, i8* %0)
  ret void
}
```

This line is interesting in particular:

```
call fastcc void @_ZN7consume20hf098deecafa4b74bkaaE(%LotsOfBytes* noalias nocapture dereferenceable(1024) %arg)
```

If I understand correctly, this means that `consume` is called with a pointer to `LotsOfBytes`, so yes, rustc optimizes passing big structures by value.